# C# Automation Visual Studio using Chrome - Hello World User

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, visual-studio-2012, automation

I am currently in the process of automating a bunch of tests for a website in my company.

I am using C# to automate them, and I need some assistance regarding the basic files I need to use in order to automate?

I am using visual studio, I understand I need selenium webdrivers for chrome, which ones is it, and how do I know I am using the correct ones?

Are there any files with this that I need to automate multiple test cases? (I will be making an excess of 100 test cases.

Kind Regards,

M

(I am also at a very hello world levels, so please try to keep terminology basic if possible?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will need to install [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.23/) which is described [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).
2. Then you'll need to download [Selenium for .NET](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/) and reference it in your project. You can quickly do it using package manager console: `Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 2.53.1`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've just installed both from the NUGET manager actually, thank you for the assistance, this has simplified the process for me and I'm grateful!